# Unhandled Exception: LateInitializationError: Field '_database@22361766' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart, bloc, sqflite

Okay so I have no idea what I've been doing wrong. My app does not work as expected and gives this unusual error -

```
E/flutter (14104): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: LateInitializationError: Field '_database@22361766' has not been initialized.
E/flutter (14104): #0      DatabaseProvider._database (package:new_appointment/database/database.dart)
package:new_appointment/database/database.dart:1
E/flutter (14104): #1      DatabaseProvider.database
package:new_appointment/database/database.dart:15
E/flutter (14104): #2      ClientProvider.getClients
package:new_appointment/…/dataproviders/client_provider.dart:17
E/flutter (14104): #3      ClientRepository.getAllClients
package:new_appointment/…/repositories/client_repository.dart:7
E/flutter (14104): #4      ClientBloc.getClients
package:new_appointment/…/blocs/client_bloc.dart:16
E/flutter (14104): #5      new ClientBloc
package:new_appointment/…/blocs/client_bloc.dart:11
E/flutter (14104): #6      new _NewAppointmentState
package:new_appointment/…/screens/new_appointment.dart:22
E/flutter (14104): #7      NewAppointment.createState
package:new_appointment/…/screens/new_appointment.dart:18
```

Looks like everything starts from the DatabaseProvider. Here is the code to it:

```
final clientTABLE = 'ClientDetails';
class DatabaseProvider {
  static final DatabaseProvider dbProvider = DatabaseProvider();

  late Database _database;

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database;
    _database = await createDatabase();
    return _database;
  }

  createDatabase() async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, "Client.db");

    var database = await openDatabase(path,
        version: 1, onCreate: initDB);
    return database;
  }

  Future initDB(Database database, int version) async {
    await database.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $clientTABLE ("
        "firstName VARCHAR, "
        "lastName VARCHAR, "
        "whatsappNo VARCHAR, "
        "email VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, "
        "location VARCHAR, "
        "projectName VARCHAR, "
        ")");
  }
}
```

ClientProvider looks something like this:

```
class ClientProvider {
  final dbProvider = DatabaseProvider.dbProvider;

  Future<int> createClient(Client client) async {
    final db = await dbProvider.database;
    var result = db.insert(clientTABLE, client.toDatabaseJson());
    return result;
  }

  Future<List<Client>> getClients({List<String>? columns, String? query}) async {
    final db = await dbProvider.database;
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> result = {} as List<Map<String, dynamic>>;
    if (query != null) {
      if (query.isNotEmpty)
        result = await db.query(clientTABLE,
            columns: columns,
            where: 'firstName LIKE ?',
            whereArgs: ["%$query%"]);
    } else {
      result = await db.query(clientTABLE, columns: columns);
    }

    List<Client> clients = result.isNotEmpty
        ? result.map((item) => Client.fromDatabaseJson(item)).toList()
        : [];
    return clients;
  }
}
```

I'm just trying to save data into a sqlite local db using sqflite package. As of now neither the newly added data shows up on the UI nor I'm able to add any new data. This LateInitializationError pops up everytime.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here ? Your help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: The `if (_database != null)` check makes no sense.  If `_database` is not initialized, the check will attempt to read from an uninitialized variable.  If you want to be able to tell if `_database` has been initialized or not, make `_database` nullable instead of `late`.

Comment: Okay. So I made _database nullable by writing: Database? _database. Also, I removed the if (_database != null) return _database line. Now It has come to a new error which says - E/flutter (14104): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>' in type cast

Comment: This error pops up inside the ClientProvider class I've mentioned above

Comment: I meant that the `if`-check makes no sense for a `late` variable; the check is appropriate (and probably should be there) if the variable is nullable.  Your cast error is a separate problem: `{} as List<Map<String, dynamic>>;` makes no sense since `{}` is a `Map` and cannot be cast to a `List`...

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be this way. Hope its help you

```
  Database? _database;

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database == null) 
        _database = await createDatabase();
    return _database;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. I solved it by changing this :

```
late Database _database;
      Future<Database> get database async {
        if (_database != null) return _database;
        _database = await createDatabase();
        return _database;
      }
```

to this :

```
 static Database? _database;
  Future<Database> get database async =>
      _database ??= await createDatabase();
```

Answer (score 0):

The following Nibha Jain's answer solved my problem. Thanks.

I was also facing the same issue. I solved it by changing this :

```
late Database _database;
        Future<Database> get database async {
           if (_database != null) return _database;
        _database = await createDatabase();
        return _database;
}
```

to this :

```
static Database? _database;
      Future<Database> get database async =>
        _database ??= await createDatabase();
```

Comment: Thanks, will you please upvote my answer if it is helpful? @Lallawmkima Lianthung